# Ubuntu Smartgit won't start

Tags: ubuntu, java, smartgit

I'm trying to get smartgit running on Ubuntu, and I'm constantly getting this error:

```
Disabling SSE42Intrinsics to work around bug 6875866.
An incompatible Java version has been detected which has been reported to cause strange bugs. Aborting now. To force SmartGit to use this Java version, set the VM property     smartgit.checkIncompatibleJava to false (use at your own risk).

Please install the latest release of the SUN Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) from:
  http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/
or if it is already installed, make sure it is used.
```

The nabble support forum doesn't work at this very moment, and I can't find any --working-- installation documentation.

I've tried to download the JRE from the link given in the readme-linux.txt file, but that bige me a single .bin file.

I've also installed the sun-java6-jre package from the synaptic manager, and notice I already had the following package installed:

- default-jre,
- openjdk-6-jre-lib
- gcj-4.x-jre-lib.

Adding sun-java6-jre didn't helped.

How can I get smartgit installed correctly ?

Comment: This probably belongs on askubuntu.com

Comment: Did you check whether the Sun JRE is used after installing it? What do `which java` and `echo $JAVA_HOME` return?

Comment: what does     update-alternatives --config java     say is your default java?

Comment: which java => /usr/bin/java
echo $JAVA_HOME => <nothing>
update-alternatives --config java => openjdk, I just had to hit "2" (java-6-sun) and the problem is solved. Please post an answer so I'll be able to reward it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this tutorial http://solaajayi.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/installing-smartgit-in-ubuntu-linux-10-04/

After this tutorial I've got **smartgit** on my ubuntu system.

Answer (score 1):

Step1 Dowload 2 files from SUN site as specified in the readme-linux.txt

`jre-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin  (installer script) and 
jre-6u24-linux-i586.bin (actual jre-1.6)`

Step2 Run as root and chmod the installer script file

`$> su -
$> chmod +x jre-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin`

Step3 Execute the installer script

`$> ./jre-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin
//Script shows "Done" at the end of the installation.`

Step4 Point to the right installation of java
Get current java source and version in case you need to undo the java switch

`$> which java
$> java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.7) (fedora-52.1.9.7.fc14-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)`

$> file /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java'

Step5 Switch between to the SUN java from OpenJDK
$> ln -f -s /usr/java/jre1.6.0_24/bin/java /usr/bin/java

Step6 Check if the switch worked

`$> java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)`

For detailed instructions on installing jre1.6 see the link

`http://java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#selfextracting`

Comment: That's a pretty complicated way. You can just: sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre , and then use the MeBigFatGuy solution to select the default java thing to use.

Comment: Yes. I couldn't install as shown by MeFatGuy - yum gave some error and Sun Update Manager(?) needs jre pre-installed (a catch22 situation). I was installing smartgit (unsuccessfully) on Fedora when I saw this post. This is a a step-by-step approach that finally worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `openjdk-7-jre` Use
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`

Answer (score 0):

SmartGit 3 (currently available as preview) works fine and out-of-the-box with OpenJDK.